# Как изменить фон на активном bottom navigation bar?

Tags: android, kotlin, bottom-navigation-view

Искал в параметрах bottom navigation bar, но там ничего не нашел подскажите как можно изменить цвет или вовсе убрать.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]